# Python Trigger a function at a specific time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code a bot(?) that will open my zoom classes in a specific time. Well the problem is when i start the code Firefox is opening but zoom page is not, so please help, btw here is my code;

```
from selenium import webdriver
import schedule
import time

path = "/home/mekroknight/Downloads/geckodriver"
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)

def tuesday_classes():
    tar1 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    tar2 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    rehbr = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    fiz1 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    fiz2 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    sprjh1 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    sprjh2 = browser.get("zoom link")

def thursday_classes():
    ... 

def saturday_classes():
    ...

schedule.every().tuesday.at("07:50").do(tuesday_classes, "Class is starting...")
schedule.every().thursday.at("07:50").do(thursday_classes, "Class is starting...")
schedule.every().saturday.at("08:40").do(saturday_classes, "Class is starting...")
```

what am i doing wrong?(By the way the reason i wrote `"zoom link"` while coding is that i didn't want strangers to join my lessons.

```
    tar1 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    tar2 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    rehbr = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    fiz1 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    fiz2 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    sprjh1 = browser.get("zoom link")
    time.sleep(2400)
    sprjh2 = browser.get("zoom link")
```

And this `tar`,`rehbr`,`fiz`,`sprjh` guys are zoom classes)

Comment: Why do you think that "nothing is happening"? what do you expect to happen? How is that different from what you observe?

Comment: If you tell the code to do something every Tuesday at 7:50, *and it isn't Tuesday at 7:50 right now*, are you expecting something to happen now anyway? What, exactly?

Comment: Does your program live or it ends after setting those schedule?

Comment: Well i want this code to open a Zoom link in Firefox and actually Firefox is opening but zoom page is not opening.

Comment: well of course i dont expact this code to work in sunday. I made a little changes and made the day sunday, but still, code is not working.

Comment: @NicLaforge it ends after opening Firefox

Comment: i did a little edit so you can understand more

Comment: Note there are well-supported options for automation on Windows, including autohotkey, schedule, etc.

Comment: Well im not using windows im on ubuntu

Comment: and i'm sure there are applications for this already, but I want to do it myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You could use this instead (`Linux-Only`):

```
import os

def open_ff():
    os.system(f"/usr/bin/firefox --new-window https://zoom.us/...")


schedule.every().tuesday.at("07:50").do(tuesday_classes, "Class is starting...")
while True: 
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then you would not need to use the `selenium-webdriver` and stuff. Firefox would just start like if you typed `/usr/bin/firefox --new-window zoom link` in a bash.

Comment: thanks but well it doesn't start at a specific time or i couldn't do it

Comment: @MekroKnight This will of course replace all of your code. Just the `tar1 = browser.get("zoom link")` parts. This should fix your problem with the zoom page not opening. You still need to do the timing yourself.

Comment: Well i did like this: https://imgupload.io/image/4WTh1 and now, it does litteraly nothing. When i start the code it will automatically ends.

Comment: Check, that `firefox --new-window zoom_link` works when you execute it in bash. If that works, `os.system()` should work as well.

Comment: it works when i do it alone, i mean like `os.system(f"/usr/bin/firefox --new-window {zoom_link}")` but when i do same as the image, it wont work

Comment: Do you have the `while True: schedule.run_pending(); time.sleep(1)` like explained here https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

Comment: thank you!!!! i finally did it! in the page `schedule.every().tuesday.at("07:50").do(tuesday_classes, "Class is starting...")` this was written a little diffrent so i tried that one and now it works!!

Comment: That makes me happy. Will add that to my answer in just a sec.